# I'm getting an error in a python discord bot tutorial

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm following this tutorial on the internet:  [tutorial](https://www.techwithtim.net/tutorials/discord-py/setup/)
And when I type the command:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite
```

I get the following output:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite
  Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (to revision rewrite) to c:\users\joshua\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-n1voybju
  WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'rewrite', assuming revision or ref.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q rewrite Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install it with pip instead:

```
pip install -U discord
```

Comment: ah thanks my mistake i didn't read correctly